# Python - Extract text from string

Tags: python, regex

What are the most efficient ways to extract text from a string?  Are there some available functions or regex expressions, or some other way?

> For example, my string is below and I want to extract the IDs as well
>   as the ScreenNames, separately.

```
[User(ID=1234567890, ScreenName=RandomNameHere), User(ID=233323490, ScreenName=AnotherRandomName), User(ID=4459284, ScreenName=YetAnotherName)]
```

Thank you!

Edit: These are the text strings that I want to pull.  I want them to be in a list.

Target_IDs = 1234567890, 233323490, 4459284
Target_ScreenNames = RandomNameHere, AnotherRandomName, YetAnotherName

Comment: Is the text you want to parse the list at the bottom of your post?

Comment: Use regex, extract each `User(ID={matching expression}, ScreenName={matching experssion})` first, then do another extraction to get what you want.

Comment: @Jakub, I revised my post.  The text I want to parse are now at the bottom of the post.  I am specifically looking to parse out 1234567890, 233323490, 4459284 and RandomNameHere, AnotherRandomName, YetAnotherName

Comment: @btquanto I'm new to regular expressions as well, any pointers for types of expressions?  I'm looking at a regex generator with a cheat sheet and what I've tried didn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import re
str = '[User(ID=1234567890, ScreenName=RandomNameHere), User(ID=233323490, ScreenName=AnotherRandomName), User(ID=4459284, ScreenName=YetAnotherName)]'
print 'Target IDs = ' + ','.join( re.findall(r'ID=(\d+)', str) )
print 'Target ScreenNames = ' + ','.join( re.findall(r' ScreenName=(\w+)', str) )
```

Output :
Target IDs = 1234567890,233323490,4459284
Target ScreenNames = RandomNameHere,AnotherRandomName,YetAnotherName

Comment: Wow, that worked perfectly!  Thank you!  Now to learn what the code is actually doing :)

Answer (score 0):

The regex I'd use would be:

```
(?:ID=|ScreenName=)+(\d+|[\w\d]+)
```

However, this assumes that ID is only digits (`\d`) and usernames are only letters or numbers (`[\w\d]`).

This regex (when combined with `re.findall`) would return a list of matches that could be iterated through and sorted in some fashion like so:

```
import re

s = "[User(ID=1234567890, ScreenName=RandomNameHere), User(ID=233323490, ScreenName=AnotherRandomName), User(ID=4459284, ScreenName=YetAnotherName)]"
pattern = re.compile(r'(?:ID=|ScreenName=)+(\d+|[\w\d]+)');

ids = []
names = [] 

for p in re.findall(pattern, s):
    if p.isnumeric():
        ids.append(p)
    else:
        names.append(p)

print(ids, names)
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex.  Usernames can have letters and numbers.

Comment: Updated to allow for that possibility. `[\d\w]` matches either a letter or a number, and `+` allows for multiple matches.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. Assuming that all your text comes in the form of

```
TagName = TagValue1, TagValue2, ...
```

You need just two calls to split.

```
tag, value_string = string.split('=')
values = value_string.split(',')
```

Remove the excess space (probably a couple of `rstrip()`/`lstrip()` calls will suffice) and you are done. Or you can take regex. They are slightly more powerful, but in this case I think it's a matter of personal taste.

If you want more complex syntax with nonterminals, terminals and all that, you'll need [lex/yacc](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ply), which will require some background in parsers. A rather interesting thing to play with, but not something you'll want to use for storing program options and such.

Comment: I'll look into this as well. Thank you.