# python Want to extract text/string from Excel cell based on string/text from another cell

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Using Python, I want to search for a text string in Col2 based on Col1. So in the example below, if the text/string is 9880, then in Col2 I want to search for text with 9880.xxx and then extract it to a new row in a new column. I want to be able to do this for multiple rows. 
The example below is contained all in one Excel row, and therefore the text in col2 is all in one Excel cell.

```
Example: data in Excel
             Col1      Col2 
             9880  | line of text  |
 single            | 9880.01       |    
 Excel             | line of text  |
 row               | 9880.02       |  
                   | line of text  |
                   | 9880.03       | 

  New column:  Colx
  Excel row1   9880.01
  Excel row2   9880.02
  Excel row3   9880.03
```

I know how to read Excel data and save it to a dataframe and write back to Excel. It's the search and and extract part I need help with. 
Maybe I could pull it off using Pandas split command, then melt, and then followed by Groupby.

I tried to look for similar examples in Stack overflow, but something that was sort of close was here: [Python - Extract text from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458087/python-extract-text-from-string). Everything else was related to using VBA. 
Any suggestions are appreciated.

Edited 06/28/2018: I think I can achieve this by using the 'findall' command, but not sure on how to construct the for loop so that it could go to the next item in the dataframe as read in from Excel. Perhaps use enumerate from the list that I am searching through.

```
9880    'line of text'
9450    'line of text'
4530    'line of text'
```